# Are Postgres table names guaranteed to be unique within a schema? within a database?

Tags: sql, postgresql, schema

While writing a Postgres query, I omitted the schema information and the query worked correctly. If the query operates within a single schema, is it ok to leave out schema information? Will this ever bite me?

e.g.

`SELECT * FROM version;`

As opposed to

`SELECT * FROM schema.version;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Table names are unique within a schema. They are definitely **not** unique for the entire database. To quote [the documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/ddl-schemas.html):

> The same object name can be used in different schemas without conflict; for example, both `schema1` and `myschema` can contain tables named `mytable`.

Having said that, usually explicitly specifying a schema is cumbersome, and just redundant. Unless you explicitly need to use a schema, you can safely omit it.

Comment: Thanks. I have a long query with many join within the same schema, would you recommend prepending `SET SCHEMA 'schema;'` before the query or running as is?

Comment: @bphi it's a matter of taste, but personally, I'm not a fan of `set schema`. Using it makes your query dependant on some external state, and you cannot just cut and drop it wherever you want (you'd need to cut the `set schema` with it). But again, it's really a matter of personal preference.